# linux wtmp randomly empties itself

Tags: linux, debian

I've had this happen about three times now.  Randomly when I log into my server and type "last" I find that there is no information given to me.  Is wtmp periodically emptied?  Is this something I should be concerned about?

Comment: Run `ls -l /var/log/wtmp*` and check if old logs were rotated by `logrotate`.

Comment: turns out they were on a schedule to rotate weekly.  Thanks, Marco.